# Conditional fields in MySQL

Tags: mysql

Is there anything like an `IF` statement that can be used in select queries in MySQL?

For example, take the following query:

```
SELECT last_online, NOW() as "current_date" FROM streamers;
+---------------------+---------------------+
| last_online         | current_date        |
+---------------------+---------------------+
| 2020-07-29 01:46:20 | 2020-07-29 01:46:23 |
+---------------------+---------------------+
```

I would like to be able to do something like the following:

```
mysql> SELECT offline as "YES" IF current_date - NOW() < 10s ELSE "NO" FROM streamers;
+-----------------+
| offline         | 
+-----------------+
| NO              | 
+-----------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes MySQL has an `IF` function https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if

> IF(expr1,expr2,expr3)
>
> If expr1 is TRUE (expr1 <> 0 and expr1 <> NULL), IF() returns expr2.
> Otherwise, it returns expr3.

So your query will be,

```
SELECT IF(`current_date` - NOW()  < 10, "YES", "NO") as offline FROM streamers;
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it.

```
SELECT
  IF(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, last_online, NOW()) > 10, "YES", "NO") as offline
FROM streamers;

+---------+
| offline |
+---------+
| NO      |
+---------+
```